# Obter intervalo de valores em objeto pandas.Dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Tenho um objeto **pandas.Dataframe** com um campo do tipo date do python. Como consigo obter um conjunto de registros de acordo com intervalo de datas?

Um exemplo do conjunto de dados(últimos 10 registros):

```
         datpre codneg     nomres modref  preabe  premax  premin  preult  \
153  2017-08-14  PETR4  PETROBRAS     R$   12.98   13.22   12.91   13.08   
154  2017-08-15  PETR4  PETROBRAS     R$   13.08   13.24   13.05   13.15   
155  2017-08-16  PETR4  PETROBRAS     R$   13.30   13.38   13.10   13.13   
156  2017-08-17  PETR4  PETROBRAS     R$   13.12   13.26   13.02   13.05   
157  2017-08-18  PETR4  PETROBRAS     R$   13.16   13.60   13.16   13.60   
158  2017-08-21  PETR4  PETROBRAS     R$   13.64   13.66   13.28   13.34   
159  2017-08-22  PETR4  PETROBRAS     R$   13.70   13.87   13.64   13.79   
160  2017-08-23  PETR4  PETROBRAS     R$   13.78   13.93   13.65   13.76   
161  2017-08-24  PETR4  PETROBRAS     R$   13.78   13.89   13.68   13.80   
162  2017-08-25  PETR4  PETROBRAS     R$   13.87   13.94   13.81   13.88   
       quatot        codisi       data    porvar  prevar  
153  31607400  BRPETRACNPR6 2017-08-14  1.003861    0.13  
154  24737300  BRPETRACNPR6 2017-08-15  0.535168    0.07  
155  44946600  BRPETRACNPR6 2017-08-16 -0.152091   -0.02  
156  23503300  BRPETRACNPR6 2017-08-17 -0.609292   -0.08  
157  66263500  BRPETRACNPR6 2017-08-18  4.214559    0.55  
158  40485900  BRPETRACNPR6 2017-08-21 -1.911765   -0.26  
159  55240700  BRPETRACNPR6 2017-08-22  3.373313    0.45  
160  47679700  BRPETRACNPR6 2017-08-23 -0.217549   -0.03  
161  32300600  BRPETRACNPR6 2017-08-24  0.290698    0.04  
162  24185600  BRPETRACNPR6 2017-08-25  0.579710    0.08
```

A coluna data contém datas no formato de date. Precisava obter o conjunto de dados dentro de um intervalo de datas.

Comment: Podes acresentar um exemplo pequeno do conjunto de dados que tens?

Comment: Estou separando um conjunto pequeno e daqui a pouco edito a pergunta.

Comment: Achei uma solução na versão em inglês do stackoverflow: ["select-dataframe-rows-between-two-dates"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29370057/select-dataframe-rows-between-two-dates)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A forma de filtrar linhas de um dataframe é usar a sintaxe de `[ ]` para selcionar linhas, mas dentro da mesma colocar uma expressão que resulte em uma série do mesmo tamanho que o dataframe, com valores True ou False.

E para fazer isso, basta comparar os elementos da coluna de data com os valores desejados - no caso, objetos datetime com a menor e a maior data.
Infelizmente a natureza das operações para criar essas séries, que abusa um pouco da sobrecarga de operadores do Python, não permite o uso da sintaxe do Python que funciona pra valores escalares "inicio < valor < fim", como usamos em notação matemática - então temos que combinar as duas operações com o operador "&"  -
que, por sua vez, exige um conjunto de parenteses por conta da precedência

```
import datetime
...

data_inicio = datetime.datetime(2017, 8, 5)
data_final = datetime.datetime(2017, 8, 15)

df_filtrado = df[(data_inicio <= df["datpre"]) &  (data_final > df["datpre"]) ]
```

(claro que as datas não precisam estar em variáveis, só fiz para melhorar a legibilidade)

## Exemplo -

Sempre é interessante deixar exemplos de código completos e reprodutíveis para que outras pessoas possam aprender e reproduzir o que está acontecendo sem ter que reproduzir tudo do zero. Então abaixo as linhas que, em uma sessão do terminal, podem criar um dataframe de testes e selecionar algumas linhas:

```
import pandas as pd, datetime
# Variável para abreviar a chamada de `datetime.datetime` mais abaixo
D = datetime.datetime

# Criando um DF com uma coluna de dias, um dia de maio de 2019 por linha:

df = pd.DataFrame({"dias":[(D(2019, 5, 1) + datetime.timedelta(days=i)) for i in range(32)    ]})

print(df)
# selecionando um subconunto de datas
df[(D(2019, 5, 5)< df["dias"]) & (df["dias"] < D(2019, 5, 10)) ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Olá, você pode usar a função iloc() do pandas que segue as mesmas notações que a lib Numpy.`dataframe.iloc[20:50,2]` ou seja, índice 20 até índice 49 e somente coluna de índice 2